'Index' object has no attribute '_format_flat'
I am only trying to load a dataframe in VSCode using the notebook extension, but as I try to display my dataframe, I get this error: AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute '_format_flat'.
Here is my code:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data/European_Soccer_Data.csv")
df

Here is the error (ran in VSCode using the Notebook extension)
AttributeError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
File ...\anaconda3\Lib\sitepackages\IPython\core\formatters.py:344, in BaseFormatter.__call__(self, obj)
    342     method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
    343     if method is not None:
--> 344         return method()
    345     return None
    346 else:

File ...\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:1136, in _repr_html_(self)
   1134 # more generally, whatever we allow in NDArrayBackedExtensionBlock
   1135 arr = cast("np.ndarray | DatetimeArray | TimedeltaArray | PeriodArray", arr)
-> 1136 return arr.T

File ...\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\format.py:1108, in to_html(self, buf, encoding, classes, notebook, border, table_id, render_links)
   1079 def format_array(
   1080     values: ArrayLike,
   1081     formatter: Callable | None,
   (...)
   1090     fallback_formatter: Callable | None = None,
   1091 ) -> list[str]:
   1092     """
   1093     Format an array for printing.
   1094 
   1095     Parameters
...
    609 def _get_columns_formatted_values(self) -> list[str]:
    610     # only reached with non-Multi Index
--> 611     return self.columns._format_flat(include_name=False)

AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute '_format_flat'

I believe that it is an error with the setup of my files because I haven't done anything major yet. I went and looked at the function triggering this issue, and I was redirected to a file called html.py
that ran:
class NotebookFormatter(HTMLFormatter):
    """
    Internal class for formatting output data in html for display in Jupyter
    Notebooks. This class is intended for functionality specific to
    DataFrame._repr_html_() and DataFrame.to_html(notebook=True)
    """
    enter code here

def _get_columns_formatted_values(self) -> list[str]:
        # only reached with non-Multi Index
        return self.columns._format_flat(include_name=False)

As you can see, above, the function returns self.columns._format_flat(...)
From what I understand from this issue, this function calls a property that is not defined in the Index object currently within my virtual environment. Is it a correct assumption, or am I missing something? If possible can someone further explain this error, and ultimately how do I prevent the triggering of this error?
Here is a sample of the csv file:
Round,Date,Time,Team,Team_Score,Opponent_Score,Opponent,Home_Score_AET,Away_Score_AET,Home_Penalties,Away_Penalties,Team_Points,Opponent_Points,season,Location,Country,Competition
ROUND 1,31/08/2002,22:30,RACING SANTANDER,0.0,1.0,VALLADOLID,,,,,0.0,3.0,2002,Home,spain,primera-division
ROUND 1,01/09/2002,21:00,RAYO VALLECANO,2.0,2.0,ALAVES,,,,,1.0,1.0,2002,Home,spain,primera-division
ROUND 1,01/09/2002,21:00,REAL SOCIEDAD,4.0,2.0,ATHLETIC BILBAO,,,,,3.0,0.0,2002,Home,spain,primera-division
ROUND 1,01/09/2002,22:00,MALLORCA,0.0,2.0,VALENCIA,,,,,0.0,3.0,2002,Home,spain,primera-division
ROUND 1,01/09/2002,22:30,VILLARREAL,2.0,2.0,OSASUNA,,,,,1.0,1.0,2002,Home,spain,primera-division
ROUND 1,01/09/2002,22:30,RECREATIVO HUELVA,2.0,3.0,MALAGA,,,,,0.0,3.0,2002,Home,spain,primera-division


That cell that just is df should display the dataframe as Jupyter will try to display what is returned by last expression using it's rich representational features. Did you try display(df)? Your traceback is incomplete so we cannot tell much from the snippet you shared. For example, it doesn't look to match the screenshot you shared. But maybe it does. Cannot tell because it is just a fraction. Plus it is very frowned upon and a No-no to post what is text code as images, or at least only images. It's not searcheable or indexable and so it is almost useless to the StackOverflow system.

Please post the code and the error as a text, not a screenshot.

Please read the guide How do I ask a good question?, especially the section 'Help others reproduce the problem' where it stresses in bold what I and toyota have pointed out. And edit your post appropriately. And try some the examples in the Pandas documentation and see if they display okay in your notebook. (Here is some self-contained code. Those examples show how you'll see it in a console. It should like rendered as HTML for you in Jupyter.) It may be something with this .csv file.

Back to what to expect with df alone in a cell or display(df) inside Jupyter...  See the top of here for a better taste of what you should see with df in a cell alone. You won't need the styler to get the plain ones like they show at the top of that page but I cannot find the page in the documentation that shows a plain dataframe display right now, and so what I reference should give you a vague sense.

Got it, I will re-edit the code. As it pertains the display(df) route, I tried it but the same traceback call is shown.

Can you provide a sample of the csv file?  If the problem is with df, just displaying the loaded frame, you could test one of summaary displayz, like df.info() or df.dtypes.

Sure, I will add it above

I decided to restart my PC, and it seems to run fine now. The display even changed. Can someone explain what could have been the issue? I never had to restart my PC with a new Extension, they usually run directly

If things are more complex, propagating changes can often take restarting or refreshing. Since VSCode isn't a browser, there's probably no easily accessed refresh? Some you need to restart. This is good to learn now as some complex extensions you'll add to Jupyter may require the same sort of thing.

This error might arise if you are using outdate version of pandas, try upgrading the pandas version
pip install --upgrade pandas

